# Silent Printing at default printer in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i am developing a Point-of-sale system but i stuck here in printing the receipt.. can i do the printing without showing the CrystalReport window?

something like this.. :D

```
private void btnPrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theStringIWantToPrint = "hello world, i am a receipt";
    Printer.print(theStringIWantToPrint);
}
```

The default printer will automatically print the string without any prompt.. :) is that possible? can i ask for a sample code to do the task?

Comment: I was under the impression you wanted to print an actual crystal report w/o showing the viewer when I first answered.  But reading over your question again I'm wondering if you meant you just want to print plain text?  Which is it, and are you trying to print to a normal printer or a receipt printer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print a report without prompting the user:

```
ReportDocument rDoc = new ReportDocument();
rDoc.Load("SomeReport.rpt");

// Do whatever else you need to setup rDoc here
// SetDatabaseLogon, VerifyDatabase, Set ParameterFields, etc.

// Find out what the Default Printer Name is
rDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "Default Printer Name";
rdoc.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0) //copies, collated, startpage, endpage
```

Alternatively, if you want to prompt the user to select a printer then just use the CrystalReportViewer.PrintReport() method.

Comment: This is using the verion of CR that comes with VS 2008.  I would hope 2010 uses the same API, but I know that prior to 2008 their API has varied wildly from version to version so you may want to post which one you're using if this doesn't do it for you.

Comment: i found some alternative here.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx

Comment: Just FYI, the methods provided for drawing strings do not always center perfectly.  There was a report I did a long time ago where I drew my own grid that was centered on the page and above it was the title.  If it weren't for the grid it would have looked fine but next to the title it showed how off center it was.  I ended up finding someone's code that would center it for me correctly.  If you find you need it I could probably dig it up for you.